# Why does my PHP socket not work on a public website?

Tags: php, sockets, minecraft

I am making a Minecraft Server status page, and to get the status of a server I use PHP with [this](https://www.webmaster-source.com/2012/07/05/checking-the-status-of-a-minecraft-server-with-php/) module, and when I test on XAMPP, it works great. When I test it on my public godaddy website, it doesn't connect.
Here's what I got when I tested locally:

**1)** Reload website, javascript ajax post -> php file
**2)** Data returns, I alert to show the data **3)** data comes back intact and correct

Here's what I got when I tested online:

**1)** Reload website, javascript ajax post -> php file
**2)** Data returns, I alert to show the data **3)** data is blank, nothing to show.

Something went wrong while trying to connect and get the server data, but there is no output in console so I can't figure out the problem.

Comment: Have you looked in your server logs?

Comment: As above, I would look at the logs. It's possible that the ability to open sockets is disabled on your hosting

Comment: I looked through some settings, and you were right, @atymic, sockets were disabled. I enabled them, but the issue is still persisting. I am getting no error logs whatsoever.

Comment: Chances are that there's some kind of block from allowing sockets to be opened for security reason. I'd check with godaddy's support.

Comment: I checked in with support and another godaddy online forum, and it seems like they don't open up custom ports. In this case, do you know of any other way to do this besides how I am trying to?

Comment: Yeah, use a VPS instead of a Web Server @Jacob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved**

Godaddy does not allow custom ports to be opened.
Solution: Use a VPS instead of a Webserver.